# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Getting the above exception in Selenium JAVA for below code . Can anyone please help me out..

```
        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/");
        List<WebElement> Listlinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        //Listlinks.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));
        System.out.println("size of links and images" + Listlinks.size());

        List<WebElement> activelinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= Listlinks.size(); i++) {
            if (Listlinks.get(i).getAttribute("href") != null) {
                activelinks.add(Listlinks.get(i));
                //System.out.println("size of active links and images" + activelinks.size());

            }
            System.out.println("size of active links and images" + activelinks.size());

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < activelinks.size() - 1; j++) {

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            String response = connection.getResponseMessage();
            connection.disconnect();
            System.out.println(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href") + response);
        }
```

Expected the list of active and broken links

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
for (int i=0; i<=Listlinks.size(); i++) {
    //...
}
```

The number of items of `Listlinks` is `Listlinks.size()`. Since the language is 0-indexed, the first element has an index of 0, the second has an index of 1 and so on, the last element having an index of `Listlinks.size() - 1` and `Listlinks.size()` is outside the bounds. So, when you do `Listlinks.get(i)` when `i` is `Listlinks.size()`, you will get the error you've got. The solution is to fix the end-sign of your loop by changing it to stop when `i` reaches `Listlinks.size()` rather than executing the inner block once more:

```
for (int i=0; i<Listlinks.size(); i++) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because in below loop condition you're using "<=" instead of "<",When the loop reaches   `i = Listlinks.size()`, it's attempting to access an element at an index that is one greater than the highest index available in Listlinks. This leads to the "IndexOutOfBoundsException" error because there's no element at that index.

Replace this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Listlinks.size(); i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < Listlinks.size(); i++)
```